# Где здесь ошибка?

Tags: c++

Пожалуйста помогите найти мою ошибку.

Почему компилятор ругается?

```
struct memb{
    int nomer;
    string score;
 memb(int nomer = 0, string score) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};


 }*cis;
```

> 24|error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of ‘memb::memb(int,
>   std::__cxx11::string)’|

Comment: у вас первый параметр со значением по умолчанию, а второй без.

Comment: Не ошибка, но `;` после определения функции - совершенно не нужная пустая декларация.

Answer (score 5):

Параметр(ы) со значением по умолчанию должен(ы) быть последним(и). У вас же после параметра со значением по умолчанию идет обычный параметр.

Если так хочется - сделайте

```
memb(string score, int nomer = 0) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};
```

Comment: у меня в коде есть также вот такая строка cis=new memb[n+1]; ,на неё компилятор говорит  48|error: no matching function for call to ‘memb::memb()’|

Comment: как это можно исправить ?

Comment: Создать конструктор по умолчанию. Или вовсе без параметров, или со всеми параметрами по умолчанию. Вы создаете массив объектов, и их нужно инициализировать...

Comment: Harry а как можно с вами по почте  связаться ?

Answer (score 1):

Данное объявление

```
struct memb{
    int nomer;
    string score;
 memb(int nomer = 0, string score) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};


 }*cis;
```

Имело бы смысл, если бы в C++ был разрешен такой вызов функций, как

```
memb( , "Hello" );
     ^^^
```

Однако такой вызов в C++ является синтаксической ошибкой. То есть вы не можете пропускать выражения аргументов при вызове функции. Можно пропускать значения выражений аргументов функций только в конце списка аргументов при условии, что пропущенным аргументам соответствуют аргументы по умолчанию.

Вы могли бы определить конструкторы данной структуры следующим образом

Данное объявление

```
struct memb{
    int nomer;
    string score;
 memb( const string &score) : nomer(0), score(score) {};
 memb(int nomer, const string &score) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};


 }*cis;
```

Либо вы могли бы использовать делегирующий конструктор. Например,

```
struct memb{
    int nomer;
    string score;
 memb( const string &score) : memb( 0, score ) {};
 memb(int nomer, const string &score) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};


 }*cis;
```

Обратите внимание, что параметр, который соответствует объекту типа `std::string` лучше объявить как константную ссылку на объект. В этому случае вы можете также в качестве аргумента использовать строковые литералы. Например,

```
memb( "Hello World!" );
```

Выражение со строковым литералом неявно преобразуется во временный объект типа `std::string` и константная ссылка на этот объект будет передана конструктору.

Также, возможно вам понадобится конструктор по умолчанию, если вы собираетесь создавать массивы элементов данной структуры.

Например,

```
struct memb{
    int nomer;
    string score;
 memb() : nomer(0) {};
 memb( const string &score) : nomer(0), score(score) {};
 memb(int nomer, const string &score) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {};


 }*cis;
```

Если создаваемый массив небольшой, то вы можете инициализировать каждый элемент массива при вызове оператора `new`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct memb
{
    int nomer;
    std::string score;

    memb() : nomer(0) {}
    memb( const std::string &score) : nomer(0), score(score) {}
    memb( int nomer, const std::string &score ) : nomer(nomer), score(score) {}
} *cis = new memb[2] { { 1, "A" }, { 2, "B" } };

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Иначе вам придется создавать элементы массива, используя конструктор по умолчанию, а затем присваивать требуемые значения членам данных каждого элемента массива.

Вы упростите себе жизнь, если вместо вручную выделять массив будете ипользлвать стандартный класс `std::vector<memb>`.

Comment: а затем я мог бы так сделать  cis=new memb[n+1];   cis[l++]=memb(cnt,tekst);   ?

Comment: @futuretourist В случае создания массива, вам нужно также в классе объявить конструктор по умолчанию.

Comment: @futuretourist Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: это ясно,а если мне нужно объявить в класс int и стринг то так memb(cnt,tekst) ?

Comment: @futuretourist Если динамический массив имеет небольшрй размер, то вы можете указать инициализаторы в списке инициализации в конце оператора new. Например, cis = new memb[n+1] { { 1, "A' }, { 2, "B" } }; А иначе объекты будут сконструированы с использованием конструктора по умолчанию, и вам придется затем явно присваивать полям объектов требуемые значения.

Comment: а если я сам хочу инициализировать значения то есть при вводе ,то как тогда это будет выглядеть ?

Comment: @futuretourist Как сделаете, так и будет выглядеть.:) Вам лучше не самому динамически выделять массив, а использовать стандартный класс std::vector. Тогда таких проблем не будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57530/discussion-between-futuretourist-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @futuretourist Я не принимаю участия в чатах. Если у вас есть новые вопросы, вы их можете задать на этом форуме в отдельных темах.